# Redirecting/Styling after a HTTP post function

Tags: javascript, html, http, express, post

Setting up Stripe on my Firebase-hosted website. 
I'm using a Cloud Function to process the charge.

I got the Stripe Checkout in a button directly prompted on my single html-site, which then redirects to the /charge function in `index.js`:

```
app.post('/charge',urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

// grab a token
const token = req.body.stripeToken;

// creating a charge, for real use add things like error handling
stripe.charges.create({
amount: 2000,
currency: "usd",
source: token, // obtained with Stripe.js
description: "Charge"
}, function(err, charge) {
res.send("You made a charge: "+ charge.id);
 });
});
```

**How am I supposed to style this /charge site?** When the charge succeeds, I want to show a "Purchase confirmed"-kinda site. Now I obviously get a white page with the response from: `res.send("You made a charge: "+ charge.id);`. Should I redirect to another `.html` in the `res.send` (if so, how?), or is there a more suitable approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `render()` method of the `res` object to render an entirely separate view.

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render